# How to select first and third column from a named rowsource in excel vba to populate a list box

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have listbox Listbox one and named rowsource "name" with 5 columns from A to E. please let me know how to populate the listbox with Column B and column D using excel vba code

Comment: Try using the `Cells` property.

Answer (score 0):

Plese, use the next way:

```
Sub testRowCol()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.rows(2) 'use your named row source here...
  Debug.Print rng.cells(1, 2).Address, rng.cells(1, 3).Address, rng.cells(1, 4).Address
End Sub
```